# RxJs: Is Observable stateful?

Tags: rxjs, reactive

I'm asking this because I tried below code:

```
//RxJs v5.5.2; NodeJs v7.10.1
var Rx = require('rxjs/Rx'); 
var observable = Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3);

var sub = observable.subscribe(console.log);
var sub1 = observable.subscribe(console.log);
```

It outputs 1 2 3 1 2 3 (new line omitted).

However, as RxJs's document says, Observable is a stream, so why does the second subscription got all the values? My understanding is, after the first subscribe, the observable has already been completed and as a stream, it should never produce a value it has already emitted.

Do I misunderstood anything?

Comment: The code works as expected. Please make your self familiar with concepts of hot and cold streams. Here is a good starting point: https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article referenced above, [Hot vs Cold Observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339)

> Observables are just functions!
>   Observables are functions that tie an observer to a **producer**. That’s it. They don’t necessarily set up the producer, they just set up an observer to listen to the producer, and generally return a teardown mechanism to remove that listener. The act of subscription is the act of “calling” the observable like a function, and passing it an observer.

So, the observable is just a pipe between a producer and observer, and the producer can (often) have the state 'baked in'.

Trying to prove that there's a producer somewhere in your example `Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3)` is a bit difficult.

The source for Observable.of is

```js
export const of = ArrayObservable.of;
```

and ArrayObservable.of

```js
static of<T>(...array: Array<T | IScheduler>): Observable<T> {
```

so the spread operator is the **producer** in this case, and `array` is the state which is passed in to the Observable.

I can't find source for the spread operator, but this ref [es6-equivalents-in-es5#spread-operator](https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5#spread-operator) gives the the following es5 equivalent

```js
var _toArray = function (arr) {
  return Array.isArray(arr) ? arr : [].slice.call(arr);
};

function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

var nums = [5, 4];
console.log(add.apply(null, _toArray(nums)));
```

Assuming `_toArray()` above is a fair approximation of spread, we can argue that spread is essentially a producer function.

So, does `Rx.Observable.of(1,2,3)` have state? We could argue yes, since the statement encloses the state, but in the equivalent

```js
const nums = [1,2,3]
const src = Rx.Observable.of(...nums)
```

we can see that the state is actually external to the observable.

**What about hot?**

A hot observable has a producer that's not reproducing it's values on demand, e.g events.

So when the producer is hot, the observable does not 'remember' state prior to the setting up of the pipeline (i.e when subscription occurs), so again the **producer** has the state not the observable.

```js
console.clear()

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(eventEmitter, 'data')

eventEmitter.emit('data', 1);
eventEmitter.emit('data', 2);
source.subscribe(x => console.log('subscription', x))
eventEmitter.emit('data', 3);
eventEmitter.emit('data', 4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/EventEmitter/5.2.4/EventEmitter.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Richard. I now know what I misunderstood. I was thinking hot v. cold observable diff only about "when", not "what". That is, I was thinking my ArrayObservable should always generate three and only three items regardless who are observing at it. An observer may miss some value because it subscribes an hot observable too late but shall never got a value the observable has already published before. My mistake is what I was thinking is Observable was actually the Producer.